# Cannot establish connection to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to server side programming but I know enough php to begin working with MySQL. So i made a phpMyAdmin account, made a database and a table in it. In dreamweaver i made a php file and connected it with the form as shown below.

HTML

```
<form action="phpinfo.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php

$username="root";
$password="xxxxx";
$database="databaseABC";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

mysql_query($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO order VALUES ('','Shirt','M','black','that photo','L','none','UL','none','Sharpiee','#E0E0E0','BIU','Lobster','bottom','L')";

mysql_close();

?>
```

However on clicking the button browser is showing the following error.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost' in C:\xampp\htdocs\college_ink\phpinfo.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\college_ink\phpinfo.php on line 7. Unable to select database
```

Please point out the error as this is my first time with server side programming?

Comment: most of them typographical errors, `localhost` missing quotes and the fact that your `mysql_query` went ahead first before the declaration of the statement itself `$query`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You are using localhost as a variable where it should be a string.

Change it to the following:

```
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
```

Comment: You may mark the answer as correct or vote up if this worked :)

Comment: @DeeJay' While it's okay to teach new persons to accept answers you should wait at least until 15 minutes after the question was asked, and you definitely shouldn't say "You should". It's the OP's decision if and when he marks an answers as accepted.

Comment: @wumm sorry :) Will take care of it next time.

Comment: @DeeJay' I added quotes to `localhost` and moved `mysql_query` to right after the query is defined. Now i only get the second error i.e.
"Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\college_ink\phpinfo.php on line 7
Unable to select database"

Comment: It means that your database name is not correct. Can you check from PHPMyAdmin what is the database name you want to use?